# How to change axis of STL in scenekit programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm working with scenekit and new to it. I want to change the axis of stl in scenekit. STL is in document directory & has axis z-up and y-forward, instead I want it as y-up & z-forward. I have tried SCNSceneSourceConvertToYUpKey but it was of no help.

Is it even possible to change axis from app?

Comment: It seems no directly way. Maybe you can import your file into a scn file. Then you can add this scene as a reference to your real scene object. Then you rotate that object. Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks,but its not working